# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of org.healthinsurance.entity.MdcnData[] out of VALUE_STRING token

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson, spring-rest

> I am trying to consume online API when i got this exception
>
> this sample of JSON

```
> "[{\"mdcnNo\":\"2\",\"grpName\":\"VARIOUS\",\"gnrcName\":\"Acetylcysteine
> 200 mg/ mL in 10? mL Inj. NMSF Cilol®\",\"trdName\":\"Cilol 200mg/ml
> Inj.\",\"apprv\":\"لا يحتاج
> موافقة\",\"gndr\":\"كلاهما\",\"unit\":\"Amp.\",\"ATCcode\":\"V03AB23\",\"ADMR\":\"\",\"dfnDayDos\":\"\",\"inInsurance\":\"1\",\"bnfCopayment\":\"25%\",\"corpCopayment\":\"75%\",\"sts\":\"1\"}]"
```

> Model Class

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class MdcnData {

```
    private String mdcnNo;
    private String grpName;
    private String gnrcName;
    private String trdName;
    private String apprv;
    private String gndr;
    private String unit;
    private String ATCcode;
    private String ADMR;
    private String dfnDayDos;
    private String inInsurance;
    private String bnfCopayment;
    private String corpCopayment;
    private String sts;
   //setter getter toString
```

> service class

```
public List<MdcnData> getAllMdcnData() {
      return Arrays.stream (restTemplate.getForObject(endPoint,MdcnData[].class))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

> controller class

```
@GetMapping(value="/get", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void run() {
        List<MdcnData> allMdcnData = consumerSrivce.getAllMdcnData();
        for (MdcnData mdcnData : allMdcnData) {
            System.out.println(allMdcnData);
        }
```

Comment: Looks like whatever service you're calling is returning JSON in a quoted string?

Comment: thanks for your response ... is there any method in JACKSON to remove quotation from JSON

Comment: If you can't change the server's response, just get it as a String, strip the quotes and parse it manually after.

Comment: ok it successfully working now after I parsed manually